# Client side database for older browsers

Tags: javascript, web-development, html, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a framework that uses IndexedDB as local storage for browsers that support it and defaults to HTML5 local storage or WebSQL for browsers that  do not support IndexedDB.

Will AngularJS provide some solution to this?

Is there anything else that could be used in order to use IndexedDB and still have support for older browsers?